# Fastest way to augment a WMT17 training set

Tags: unix, sed

I have a WMT17 training dataset with 3,961,179 lines.

From these lines I would like to augment 198,058 random lines, e.g. by inserting a `\tbewegen` (`\t` is a tab character) at the end of each line containing the word "move".

The word "move" can be anywhere in the sentence, and it is a substring of sentences like

```
1. There was more behind this move than simply wishing to expand their product portfolio .
2. move and collect miles
3. January 16 - Pro@@ hi@@ bition begins in USA . Many li@@ qu@@ or @-@ lo@@ ving Americans move to France .
.
.
.
```

if the substring "move" appears in a line, then the sentence should look like this

```
1. There was more behind this move than simply wishing to expand their product portfolio .\tbewegen
2. move and collect miles\tbewegen
3. January 16 - Pro@@ hi@@ bition begins in USA . Many li@@ qu@@ or @-@ lo@@ ving Americans move to France .\tbewegen
.
.
.
```

For this I already made a script, but I found out that an augmentation of 10 lines takes about 2 minutes and 198,058 lines would take 39,611 minutes.

Here is my bash script:

```
sed -n '=' train.de | shuf | head -198058 > lines

cat lines | while IFS= read -r line ;
do 
sed -i.bak "${line}s/move/$/\tbewegen/" train.de; 
done
```

Is there a way to shorten the process so that I don't have to wait several days?

Update: Assuming I want to apply the insert before/after operations from https://www.golinuxhub.com/2017/06/sed-insert-word-after-match-in-middle/. How to rewrite the awk code in the solution?

Edit:

You can randomly insert a word before or after a matched word with these commands:

```
awk -i inplace '(NR==FNR){a[$1];next}
    (FNR in a) && gsub(/\<the\>/,"Before &")
     1
    ' <(shuf -n 198058 -i 1-$(wc -l < n_train)) n_train

awk -i inplace '(NR==FNR){a[$1];next}
    (FNR in a) && gsub(/\<the\>/,"& After")
     1
    ' <(shuf -n 198058 -i 1-$(wc -l < n_train)) n_train
```

Comment: Is that `sed` line in the while loop correct?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. sed is difficult.

Comment: I assume `\t` is the <tab>-character?

Comment: That's right! `\t` is a tab character! According to Fairseq, it is the only way to add a constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following command should help you here. It reads a sequence of random numbers followed by the processing of the file. This does not do an inplace modification but prints the output to the screen. A redirection will save the file.

```
awk '(NR==FNR){a[$1];next}
     (FNR in a) && /\<move\>/ {$0=$0 "\tbewegen"}
     1
    ' <(shuf -n 198058 -i 1-$(wc -l < train.de)) train.de
```

This contains out of a couple commands:

**1. get a random selection of line numbers:**

```
shuf -n 198058 -i 1-$(wc -l < train.de)
```

This line generates a random selection of 198058 numbers between the range 1-N where N is the total number of lines in the file `train.de` which is given by `awk 'END{print NR}' train.de`. This line replaces the initial line in your code:

```
sed -n '=' train.de | shuf | head -198058 > lines
```

**2. use awk to do the rest:**

```
awk '(NR==FNR){a[$1];next}(FNR in a) && /\<move\>/{$0=$0 "\tbewegen"}1' file1 file2
```

We use awk here to read the input of file1 (the output of `shuf`) and store all of it in an array `a` which is used as a lookup table. When the first file is read, we check the record number (line number) of the second file `FNR` and check if we have it in the lookup table `a`. If this is true, we check if the line contains the word "move". If both conditions are met, update that line by adding `\tbewegen` to it.

You can now store this output in a new file.

This will work much faster than the previous version as this only reads the file twice, where in your example you were reading it 198059 times.

Comment: Thanks @kvantour: how can I say, that I want to add \tbewegen if the sentence contains "move". where can I give "move" as input?

Comment: So you want to add the string "/tbewegen" to every randomly selected line if and only if that randomly selected line contains the word "move"

Comment: Correct! This is the way I want.

Comment: @RamónWilhelm updated

Comment: @RamónWilhelm Just note that `/move/` will also find a match in `remove`. I am mentioning this only because you use the word *word*, not *string* or *substring*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew which seems in line with the line mentioned in the OP. For a full correct implementation we would need to see how the input looks like and more details about the word "move"

Comment: Thank you! One more Questions: What can I do, that only "move" is selected? What if I want the constraint `\tbewegen` directly inserted before or after the term "move"? What if I want to replace every word "move" in the whole train set?

Comment: What details about "move" do you need to know?

Comment: I've tested `awk '(NR==FNR){a[$1];next}(FNR in a) && /move/{$0=$0 "\tbewegen"}1' <(shuf -n 198058 -i 1-$(wc -l < n_train)) n_train` on the n_train file, which consists of English terms. Unfortunately, after I use `grep -w "\tbewegen"` I've found no constraint added.

Comment: @RamónWilhelm If you want to do different things with the word "move" you have to give more details. But generally, from what you are writing, the command "sub" or "gsub" (part of awk) will be of assistance here.

Comment: @RamónWilhelm details about the word "move" imply (a) is it a word or substring (b) is it a field value or encapsulated between special characters (c) is it at the beginning, end, or in a particular field location ... etc.

Comment: I just want to annotate the term "move", so I can later test on a trained model via Dynamic Beam Allocation how the translation looks like if I add to a sentence the constraint "bewegen".

https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/blob/main/examples/constrained_decoding/README.md

Comment: @RamónWilhelm without example input, it is difficult for us to help. Can you update your question and show us a minimal example file that might be of help here?

Comment: Question is updated now. I hope the information will help.

Comment: @RamónWilhelm according to my tests, the above will work. If it does not work, I suggest a step by step debugging of the two commands. But I do not forsee any issue here.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @kvantour: You helped me a lot! 

One more question: Assuming I want to do this insert before/after operations from https://www.golinuxhub.com/2017/06/sed-insert-word-after-match-in-middle/ . What can I do to change your code above. I edit my question for this.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
grep -n move file | shuf | head -198058 | sed 's/:.*/s#$#\\tbewegen#/' | sed -f - file
```

Use grep to find (with line number) all lines containing `move`.

Shuffle these lines using shuf.

Take the first 198058 line numbers.

Use sed to build a sed script from the line numbers that appends `\tbewegen` to each line identified in the file.

Pass the sed script into another invocation of sed using the `-f` option and play it out against the original file.

If the 198508 line may or may not contain the word `move`, use:

```
seq $(wc -l <file) | shuf | head -198058 | sed 's/$/s#$#\\tbewegen#/' sed -f - file
```